# Using Mongo Geospatial queries on lots of data

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose, location, geospatial

I am using a Mongo database with mongoose in Nest, a typescript server framework.

I have 2 mongo collections, one contains 20,000 user locations. The other collection contains 10,000 Point of Interests gathered from Google Places API.

I want to now find intersections between gathered locations and these places (which contain a lat and lng GeoJSON point).

In other words, I am looking to see where in relation to these POI's users were.

Currently, I have an async method that will find all the locations that are near a point, using the nearSphere operator.

Then I think the next step will be to then iterate over each place (10,000 of them) in the mongo collection and run this method on each location. That way I will have a list of which POI's were 'nearby' when that specific location was caught.

Is there a better way to do this? With regards to performance I believe this way will struggle. I cannot find a mongo geospatial query that will let me compare 2 sets of locations together.

- Get all locations near point

```
async findAllNearPlace(coords): Promise<Location[]> {
    return await this.locationModel.find(
      {
        location:
          { $nearSphere:
              {
                $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: coords },
                $minDistance: 0,
                $maxDistance: 100
              }
          }
      }
    );
  }
```

Each POI - check locations:

```
async findUsersInProximity(places): Promise<Location[]> {
    const locations = [];
    let i = places.length - 1;
    while (i > 0) {
      await this.findAllNearPlace(
        places[i].location.coordinates
      ).then(intersectingLocations => {
        locations.push(...intersectingLocations);
        i--;
      });
    }
    return await locations;
  }
```

As expected, the performance of this is poor and takes minutes.

Answer (score 0):

What you can probably do, is to make an aggregate function with a lookup, I did not test it, and I don't know for sure if it is a better performance, but you can do something similar to the following:

```
let pipeline = [
        {
            $geoNear: {
                includeLocs: "location",
                distanceField: "distance",
                near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: "$$point" },
                maxDistance: 20,
                spherical: true
            }
        }
    ];

UsersModel.aggregate([{
   $lookup : {
     from : 'locations',
     let : {point : '$address'}, //whatever the field for the coordinates is 
     pipeline ,
     as : 'places'   
   }
}])
```

Comment: I am trying to get this to work. So 'let : {point : '$address;} - that would be the geojson point I have? Looks like this -> location: {
    type: { type: String },
    coordinates: []
  },
And UsersModel would that be the location model or places model?